# Iterative method non convergent for singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the splitting $A=M-N$ we want to show that the general iteration :
$$ x_{k+1}=M^{-1}Nx_k +M^{-1}b $$ is not convergent in general if $A$ is singular even that if $M$ is nonsingular
Any ideas please or counterexamples please ?

Comment: Your claim is not generally true. The stationary iteration can converge to a solution of $Ax = b$ if $A$ is singular. In general, the iteration converges if and only if $M^{-1}N$ is semiconvergent. For example, the weighted Jacobi method $(0 < \omega < 1)$ converges to a strictly positive solution of $Ax = 0$ when $A$ is an irreducible singular M-matrix. The book "Nonnegative Matrices in the Mathematical Sciences" by Berman and Plemmons is a good resource.

Comment: @K.Miller i am sorry i am just looking for a counter example ill edit the problem

Comment: I think this works. By induction and the substitution $N = M - A$, you have 

$$x_{k+1} = (I - M^{-1} A)^{k+1} x_{0} + [I + (I - M^{-1} A)^{k}] M^{-1} b$$ 

which converges $\iff \lvert (I - M^{-1} A) \rvert < 1$. Try

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}, \quad M = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\
0 & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the error equation down, something like @Mattos has writen. the error equation contains a $M^{-1}$$b$ term. since in order for the relation to be convergent, the error has to go to zero, the $M^{-1}$$b$ term prevents it and it doesn't converge.